# ChartJS - Line Chart - Tracking correlation between multiple datasets with large range in values

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart

I need to create a Line chart, which works with multiple datasets, and with numbers that vastly differ from dataset to dataset

For example

```js
// Tracks how much on average a customer has spend
const averagePurchaseValueDataset = {
  label: 'Average Purchase Value',
  dataset: [25.50, 28.50, 24.30, 26.40 ]
}

// Tracks on average how much the customer spends browsing the app
// tracked in seconds
const sessionDurationDataset = {
  label: 'Session Duration',
  dataset: [80, 120, 90, 85, 93]
}

// Tracks how many products the customer has purchased in one session
const averageItemsPurchased = {
  label: 'Average Items Purchased',
  dataset: [3, 2, 1, 1]
}
```

I need to create a single chart with 3 different lines on it, which are stacked on top of each other.

ChartJS does this by default when the datasets consist of similar values ( like 1-10 ), however, in my datasets, the ranges vary vastly - one dataset can have numbers between 1-10 and another one 5000-1000, but I still want them stacked on top of each other.

The goal of this chart is not to compare the literal values in each dataset, but their changes from one interval to the next.

For example these two datasets `[10, 11]` and `[1000, 1100]` should plot two lines which are stacked exactly on top of each other, because the difference is 10% in both cases

Answer (score 0):

i think if you want to create a single chart with 3 different lines, you have to make the data in one `dataset`. sorry im not good in explaining things but you can checked code below.

```
const data = {
  label: 'Multi Line',
  dataset: [
            {label: 'Average Purchase Value',
             data: [25, 28, 24, 26]}, 
            {label: 'Session Duration',
             data: [80, 120, 90, 85]},
            {label: 'Average Items Purchased',
             data: [3, 2, 1, 1]},
           ]
}
```

hope it can help you

Comment: This is what I intend to do, however, because the numbers in each dataset are vastly different from each other, the lines will be drawn far away from each other and I want them to be stacked

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the Multi-axis feature of ChartJS

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html